# SfGoogleAnalytic Plugin Usage

Tags: symfony1, symfony-plugins

I have downloaded sfGoogleAnalyticsPlugin to my plgin directory and do all of its settigs.Now i want to implement this to one of my page.How i use it, to view my site analytic result to my page.

I need a code example.

Anybody knows please help.Help is highly appreciated.

companion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sfGoogleAnalyticsPlugin only inserts the javascript code to load GA, it doesn't give you access to analytics results - you need to log into Google Analytics for that. If you've set up your `app.yml` and `filters.yml` as explained in the README file, then the code should be automatically inserted into the bottom of every output page, and you don't need to do anything else.

If you want to embed analytics data onto your site (like, how many visitors you have), then sorry, there aren't any existing Symfony plugins that do this. You'll need to use the [Google Analytics API](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/home.html), which uses the GData standard (based on Atom). Zend Framework includes classes to make calls to GData services and [getting to ZF in Symfony](http://www.slideshare.net/weierophinney/using-zend-framework-with-symfony) is straightforward.

I had more helpful links, but StackOverflow's restricting me to only two, so sorry!

Comment: thanks you for your reply,could u please send me the more helpful link